# ¿Como mostrar un dato de mi base de datos según el identificador que tenga?

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos, pdo, foreach

Me llamo facundo rodriguez estoy trabajando en un proyecto que se trata sobre una agenda electrónica de turnos, el tema de mi problema esta en que al momento de mostrar el turno del paciente me gustaría que se mostrara sus datos pero no logro traer de la base de datos ese campo y lograr mostrarlo.

Estuve intentando con un foreach sacando los datos y si se muestra pero solo se muestra los últimos datos ingresado y no me sirve eso.

Lo que quiero hacer es que al momento de tocar el botón del paciente muestre los datos de ese paciente y no del ultimo o de otro.

Como puedo traer los datos del paciente que selecciono?

Imagen del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código que muestra el turno ingresado:

```
      foreach($paciente as $pedro){
        if ($pedro->ID_PACIENTE === $turnosFiltrados->ID_PACIENTE) {
          
        $pacineteCedula = $pedro->CEDULA_PACIENTE;
        $pacienteName = $pedro->NOMBRE_PACIENTE;
        $pacienteNickName = $pedro->APELLIDO_PACIENTE;
        $pacienteMovil = $pedro->TELEFONO_PACIENTE;
        $pacienteDireccion = $pedro->DIRECCION_PACIENTE;
        $pacienteEmail = $pedro->EMAIL_PACIENTE;
        $fotoAntes = $pedro->FOTO_ANTES_PACIENTE;
        $fotoDespues = $pedro->FOTO_DESPUES_PACIENTE;
        }
       

      }
      

       $x = 0; 
       while ($x < 25) {

        $turnosFiltrados = array_filter($turno, function ($dato) use ($hora_s, $x, $sucursalDrop, $PROfesional, $fecha) {
            return ($dato->HORA_INICIO == $hora_s[$x]) && ($dato->NOMBRE_SUCURSAL == $sucursalDrop) && ($dato->FECHA == $fecha) && ($dato->PROFESIONAL == $PROfesional);
        });
        
        
        
        if ($turnosFiltrados) {
          
         
            $dato = current($turnosFiltrados);
            ?>
            <tr style="background:#dc35451f;">
         
            <td style="width:7%; margin-left: 10px;"><strong><?php echo substr($dato->HORA_INICIO, 0, -3);?> a <?php echo substr($dato->HORA_FINAL, 0, -3); ?></strong></td>
            <td style="width:50%; margin-left: 10px;">
            <input type="checkbox"  id="btn-modal2" value="">
                  <label for="btn-modal2" class="lbl-modal2 btn-success"><strong>Paciente: </strong><?php echo $dato->NOMBRE_PACIENTE ?></label>
                  <div class="modal2">
                    <div class="contenedor2">
                      <header>Flicha Paciente</header>
                     
                      <label for="btn-modal2" style="position: absolute; color: white;"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></label>
                      <div class="contenido2">
                      
                      <div><?php echo $pacineteCedula ?></div>
                      <div><?php echo $pacienteName ?></div>
                      <div><?php echo $pacienteNickName ?></div>
                      <div><?php echo $pacienteMovil ?></div>
                      <div><?php echo $pacienteDireccion ?></div>
                      <div><?php echo $pacienteEmail ?></div>
                      <img src="<?php echo $fotoAntes ?>" alt="">
                      <img src="<?php echo $fotoDespues ?>" alt="">

           
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Mi consulta a la base de datos es:

```
$consulta1 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM pacientes;");
$paciente = $consulta1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Bueno ese seria el error que no logro encontrar, tratar de mostrar los datos del paciente correcto y no el ultimo siempre, muchas gracias desde ya.

Comment: Necesito una ayudita plz :c

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente tu error es que haces un bucle pero fuera de la ejecución de todo lo demás, con lo que te quedas con el último dato que recoge la aplicación

```php
  foreach($paciente as $pepe){
        $fefe = $pepe->TELEFONO_PACIENTE;
      }
```

Si cierras ahí se ejecuta el bucle y se actualiza todo el rato hasta que coge acaba el bucle. Cuando termina siempre $fefe vale el último teléfono del paciente.

Yo te recomendaría que cambiaras la forma de acceso a la aplicación y que cojas sólo los datos que necesitas cuando los necesites. En vez de hacer tantas consultas de tipo SELECT * hacer la consulta de los datos que necesitas en cada momento.

Es un poco chapuza pero si como dices en el comentario quieres seguir usando esta estructura podrías hacer algo así

```php
  foreach($paciente as $pepe){
    if ($pepe->CODIGO_PACIENTE === $turnosfiltrados->CODIGO_PACIENTE
    {
      $fefe = $pepe->TELEFONO_PACIENTE;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Si es verdad que el bucle esta fuera porque si lo agrego adentro me duplica todos los campos x2 , y Tenes razón con lo de las consultas no es necesario tantas jejeje eso ahí lo arreglo, pero el tema es poder sacar el dato del teléfono de otra forma que no sea con ese bucle, como podría hacer??

Comment: Con lo de CODIGO_PACIENTE te referís a la Id?, en ese caso lo probé y no me muestra nada, entonces intente agregar el código tanto afuera del White como adentro y sigue sin mostrar datos :c. En el comentario me refería a hacer otro bucle o algo que no sea un foreach, sabes que otra función puedo hacer?

Comment: Alguien me podría ayudar con ese problema? porque no me funciona esa respuesta que mando @gynch :cccc